# Auto-repeat "unread SMS message" notification sound

Tags: applications, sms, htc-one, alerts

I'm about to replace my "dumb" old mobile phone with an HTC One M8, but (initially, at least) there are likely to be days when I never even think about using it.

My old phone was set to beep once a minute until I activated it to read any messages, which was good because if someone sent me a text overnight I'd be repeatedly reminded to look at it when I got up next day (I don't normally take my phone to bed).

On the downside, if someone else gets up before me they have to put up with the phone constantly beeping (or invade my privacy by activating the phone, or bury it under cushions, or whatever! :)

I've lived with that imperfect solution for some years now, but I was kinda hoping for a way to give me much more control. What I'd *really* like is the ability to make my phone raise an audio alert every minute initially, with the time interval between alerts gradually increasing so it's maybe only every hour or two after a while.

Well, if we're talking about what I [*really, really want*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/What-You-Really-Want/dp/1580053440), obviously I don't want a beep at all - I want a way to recognise who *sent* the text, and to synthesise voice output saying they've texted me.

Anyway, that's the gist of what I'm after. Am I likely to be able to find anything good?

Comment: @beeshyams: Thanks. But I wasn't really asking for specific app recommendations - I'd be more than happy just to be told that the kind of thing I want to do is doable (and is the kind of thing *others* want to do, so configurable abilities for this aspect of functionality are commonly available). It might be that there are no suitable API's enabling a general-purpose app to handle such event, or control the frequency at which it gets reactivated to raise another repeat alert. As yet, I have no idea.

Comment: Oh OK..sorry - it sounded like that and you may suitably amend your question- my intention was to avoid closure on grounds of app recommendation- meanwhile I have posted solution. Give it a shot- it addresses what  you said is *really wanted* so doesn't address the earlier part

Comment: @beeshyams: I've ordered my new phone, but it won't arrive for a week or two. I had a quick look at what Macrodroid can do, but it doesn't seem likely it'll do exactly what I want. More to the point, the lack of response (present company excepted, ty! :) suggests that few other people are particularly interested in this level of control over how phone alerts work, so  I'm not *likely* to find what I want. Maybe my next step will be to find out if the necessary Android APIs exist for such a feature (i.e. - could I, at least *in principle,* code it up myself?).

Comment: That's perfectly fine... All the best and hope you post your own reply when it is satisfactorily done

Comment: @beeshyams: Oh. I see you've deleted your answer. Perhaps it's "gaming" the system, but I'm thinking in terms of editing my question text when I finally *do* get the device, in hopes that this will "bump" it in the "active posts" list, so maybe I'll get another bite at the cherry. But many thanks for your responses, anyway.

Comment: Maybe I will revert later when you do get your device and hope to see if I can contribute. Reason for deletion is simple, the solution doesn't match your needs. So I will give it a shot once you get the device and need becomes clear